# OSX Eclipse CDT stalls at the start of debugging: "Configuring GDB"

Tags: c, macos, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I have installed Eclipse CDT and GDB.
I created a simple "Hello World" C project.

When I try to debug the project, GDB starts to behave very chaotic: I am able to debug a few times, step through the code, etc., but then it starts stalling at the begining of the next debug session with the message "Configuring GDB".

After I restart Eclipse CDT sometimes I still cannot debug, and sometimes I can, but also just for a few times, and then again the same problem comes up: stalls with "Configuring GDB" message.

I have tried hard to find the pattern, but failed.

What could be the reason for such a chaotic behaviour?

p.s.
I forgot to mention that I did sign the `/usr/local/bin/gdb` executable (and verified it with `codesign --verify --verbose gdb`).

**Edit:**
The screenshot shows the 2 stuck sessions:

[image]

Comment: Why are you starting out programming using these obsolete tools?  Why not use Xcode?

Comment: @trojanfoe Because I just came from Windows where I used Eclipse. And because soon I will be targeting fixed-point DSP platforms. Does that make sense?

Comment: You wrote C on Windows using Eclipse CDT?

Comment: Yes, and it worked nice.

Comment: There are better tools available to developers on both Windows and macOS which are more modern, more popular and better supported.  Getting answers to issues with those tools is much easier.  You seem to have chosen a very difficult path for yourself for some reason.  But good luck I guess.